# Trouble formatting a list of strings into columns

Tags: c#, string, list, formatting

sorry to be a pain but i'm having trouble formatting my list of strings into columns, in c#.
What i'm using is an input file such as;
"aa bbb cccc ddddd eeeeee fffffff"

and using a character limit ( word wrap) i need to space the words out like so
Output: Wrap = 20

```
aa    bbb    cccc
ddddd eeeeee fffffff
```

At the moment i can get the number of words per line, but for example if a word cannot fit because of the wrap, my program puts it onto another line, however i need to maintain the same number of strings per line so the first line would have 4 strings, but the rest have 5 because they have strings which are smaller.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fixed column size or no?

Comment: No, the columns can be any size, as the spacing is meant to put them in line, and it doesn't exceed the wrap. Just the amount of strings on the line has to be the same.except the last line can have less

Comment: Could you elaborate on the string limit per line? I think I understand what you're saying, but I'm not sure what you want if you have say 5 strings on the first line and you need 5 larger strings on the next line causing it to wrap, but this violates the "same number of strings per line" rule.

Comment: There is a character wrap per line (e.g. 21 characters including spaces), and each line must contain the same number of strings (e.g. 3 strings per line) except for the last line. Each string needs to align with the string above in a column style, hope this helps clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

You could work out your spacing for each column by looping through every nth item in your array.

For example if you know the number of words per line, say it's 3 words per line, you can get every 3rd element, starting from your first element to get the first columns longest word.

so you'd have a for loop:

```
int longestWord = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i += wordsPerLine)
{
    if(array[i].Length > longestWord)
        longestWord = array[i].Length;
}
```

Not sure how you'd implement this for every column but it's an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is complicated
you could first get the number of groups doing a split on the string and then get the number of chars in each group.
When you have that, you can start making groups, and you stop when one of the subgroups exceeds the limit

```
//creates groups and lengths arrays
string letters = aaa bbbb ccc dd eeeeeee ffffffffff gggggggggggggggg hh iiiiiiiiii;
string[] groups = letters.split(" ");
int[] lengths = new int[groups.length]
    for(int i = 0; i<groups.length, i++){
    lengths[i] = groups[i].length;
}
int numberofrows;
//starts doing groups: is one element is more that 20, then if 2 elements are more 
//than 20, 3 elements more than 20....
// when a sum is more than 20, then the last amount of groups was the one to use
for(int i = 0, i<groups.length<i++){
    for(int j = 1, j<=groups.length, j++)
        int sum = add(i, j) 
        if(sum > limit){
            numberofrows = j-1;
            return;
        }
    }
}

//this makes the addition of several elements of the array, next to the other
public int add(int index, id sums){
    int sum = lengths[index];
    for(int i = 0, i<=sums;i++){
        sum += lengths[index+i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```